# Ruby on Rails - Mysql2::Error: The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have upgraded my Ruby on Rails project Ruby version to 3.0.6 from 2.5.8. My Ruby on Rails version is 6.1.7.6. After I upgraded the Ruby version, now I get a lot of following errors while using Rails console. It was not the case with Ruby v2.5.8. It seems it does not occur while using the app but it occurs only from console.

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `_query': Mysql2::Error: The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity. See wait_timeout and interactive_timeout for configuring this behavior. (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/lib/mysql2/client.rb:151:in `_query': The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity. See wait_timeout and interactive_timeout for configuring this behavior. (Mysql2::Error)
```

Here is my database.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  wait_timeout: 30 
  timeout: 500
  reconnect: true
  strict: false
  host: somehostname
  port: someportnumber
  username: someusername
  password: somepassword
  database: somedatabasename
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  pool: 13

development:
  primary:
    <<: *defaults
  shard1:
    <<: *defaults
    database: shard1
  shard2:
    <<: *defaults
    database: shard2
```

I tried downgrading mysql2 gem to 0.5.4 from 0.5.5 but it has not resolved the issue. Moreover, I tried to increase `timeout` in database.yml but that also does not seem to resolve the issue. It seems `reconnect` option in database.yml does not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

It's the wait_timeout setting of 30 seconds in your database.yml. The wait_timeout is `The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it`. The mysql2 gem is by default a noninteractive client (unless you explicitly built it with CLIENT_INTERACTIVE). Maybe remove that `wait_timeout` setting, the default of 8 hours seems reasonable.

Comment: But, I want to understand why it has started happening after upgrading Ruby version to 3.0.6. It didn't happen on v2.5.8 at all with exact same database.yml.

Comment: Upgrading ruby may have slowed down something somewhere. Check your start-up times from v2 to v3, if its slower in v3 that explains why you see the issue otherwise I dont have a good explanation if the code is exactly the same and only ruby has changed but I doubt thats the case, something must have changed and slowed things down.